# Dockerized Gitlab-runner can't find Gitlab container

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-compose

Beginner here :)

I’ve set up a Gitlab instance on my company’s local network.
It is hosted in a docker container, running on a dedicated server, whose hostname is “**devserver**”
This Gitlab instance is reachable via “https://mycompanygit”, because the network DNS is set to redirect mycompanygit to the local ip of devserver.
On devserver, there is another container running, a nginx reverse-proxy, which redirects http and https requests for mycompanygit to the gitlab container.
Now I’d like to add a third container, a Gitlab-runner instance.
So I run the following command, taken from here.

```
docker run --rm -t -i -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner --name gitlab-runner gitlab/gitlab-runner register \
  --non-interactive \
  --executor "docker" \
  --docker-image alpine:3 \
  --url "https://mycompanygit" \
  --registration-token "MY_REGISTRATION_TOKEN" \
  --description "docker-runner" \
  --tag-list "docker,aws" \
  --run-untagged \
  --locked="false"
```

I get:

```
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=i3ygCNvW status=couldn't execute POST against https://mycompanygit/api/v4/runners: Post https://mycompanygit/api/v4/runners: dial tcp: lookup mycompanygit on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host
PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems
```

How do I get the Gitlab-runner to see the Gitlab instance ? I don’t even know if it’s related to Docker or Gitlab ?

Also: the gitlab and nginx instances have been setup together with docker-compose, does that matter?

Thanks a lot :) Please tell me if I’m not clear, I’ll try to reformulate

Answer (score 0):

The GitLab Runner cannot resolve an ip for the the GitLab instance because it is using Google's DNS for domain name resolution, and Google's DNS knows nothing about `mycompanygit`. See the end of your ERROR line:

> ... lookup mycompanygit on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host

The simplest solution would be to put in the ip address you used in your company DNS for the host `mycompanygit` into the GitLab-runner config and not bother with DNS for the runner.